# how to popup modal before window close?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a fancybox jquery plugin, what i need is to make sure before the website close a modal popup up and get us the details for submission to a form.

Please let us know how to make sure that before close a website a modal box fires up.

Have tried using unload method. It works when you use return but in return you can not use a form.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`onbeforeunload`](http://javascript.gakaa.com/onbeforeunload-description.aspx) event like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')){
       // user leaves
   }
   else{
      // your code
   }
};
```

Comment: you are exactly right.. I agree the only problem being i dont want to show the confirmation box, instead of it, i want to show my own popup at which i will be asking for subscription.